# How to keep the android background picture resolution the same, after popping a AlertDialog?

Tags: android

In my application, I have a background picture and a AlertDialog box. but when the dialog box popped up it made my background darker! Is there anyway that I can keep the same resolution for my background while I am showing a AlertDialog in android API 19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this on your instance of `AlertDialog`:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHI‌​ND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```